# Undefined in a Function with an Arrays inside from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to list a lot of arrays from another file,

[image]

when I do a "for" to read any array inside.

[image]

The code compile do all the list, but when finish the last the code gave me is undefined. How do I fix that?.

I put images from the code.  I let you both codes if you want

```html
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "original_title": "Joker",
      "title": "Joker",
      "vote_average": 8.6,
      "overview": "Arthur Fleck es un hombre ignorado por la sociedad, cuya motivación en la vida es hacer reír. Pero una serie de trágicos acontecimientos le llevarán a ver el mundo de otra forma. Película basada en Joker, el popular personaje de DC Comics y archivillano de Batman, pero que en este film toma un cariz más realista y oscuro.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-04"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Maleficent: Mistress of Evil",
      "title": "Maléfica: Maestra del Mal",
      "vote_average": 7.2,
      "overview": "Secuela de \"Maléfica\" que cuenta la vida de Maléfica y Aurora, así como las alianzas que formarán para sobrevivir a las amenazas del mágico mundo en el que habitan.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-18"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Terminator: Dark Fate",
      "title": "Terminator: Destino Oscuro",
      "vote_average": 6.8,
      "overview": "Sarah Connor une todas sus fuerzas con una mujer cyborg para proteger a una joven de un extremadamente poderoso y nuevo Terminator.",
      "release_date": "2019-11-01"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "The Lion King",
      "title": "El rey león",
      "vote_average": 7.1,
      "overview": "Un remake del clásico animado de Disney de 1994 'El rey león' que estará dirigido por Jon Favreu. Simba (Donald Glover) es el hijo del rey de los leones, Mufasa, y heredero de todo el reino. Pero cuando su padre es brutalmente asesinado por su tío Scar, decidirá huir, dejando vía libre para que su tío tome el puesto de su padre como líder pelisonline.co de la manada. En su camino, Simba se encuentra con el suricato pelisonline.co Timón y el jabalí Pumba, que le enseñarán a vivir la vida sin preocupaciones. Pero el joven león se verá obligado a decidir entre su vida libre de problemas o su destino como rey .",
      "release_date": "2019-07-18"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "葉問4",
      "title": "Ip Man 4",
      "vote_average": 5.4,
      "overview": "Ip Man, el título de la cuarta película que seguirá contando la vida del mítico maestro de Bruce Lee, lanzó su primer tráiler, que se ha vuelto viral y ha sido reproducido miles de veces en YouTube. Para muchos seguidores del cine de artes marciales, Ip Man es un de las mejores sagas del género. La película volverá a ser protagonizada por Donnie Yen y estará dirigida por Wilson Yip.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-18"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw",
      "title": "Fast & Furious: Hobbs & Shaw",
      "vote_average": 6.5,
      "overview": "Desde que Hobbs, agente del Servicio de Seguridad Diplomática de Estados Unidos, y el británico Shaw, proscrito sin ley, se enfrentaron por primera vez, solo han intercambiado bofetadas y malas palabras. Pero cuando las despiadadas acciones de Brixton, un anarquista cibergenéticamente mejorado, amenazan el futuro de la humanidad, ambos se unen para derrotarlo.",
      "release_date": "2019-08-01"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Spider-Man: Far from Home",
      "title": "Spider-Man: Lejos de Casa",
      "vote_average": 7.6,
      "overview": "Peter Parker decide irse junto a Michelle Jones, Ned y el resto de sus amigos a pasar unas vacaciones a Europa después de los eventos ocurridos en Vengadores: EndGame. Sin embargo, el plan de Parker por dejar de lado sus superpoderes durante unas semanas se ven truncados cuándo es reclutado por Nick Fury para unirse a Mysterio (un humano que proviene de la Tierra 833, una dimensión del Multiverso, que tuvo su primera aparición en Doctor Strange) para luchar contra los Elementales (cuatro entes inmortales que vienen de la misma dimensión y que dominan los cuatro elementos de la Naturaleza, el fuego, el agua, el aire y la tierra) . En ese momento, Parker vuelve a ponerse el traje de Spider-Man para cumplir con  su labor.",
      "release_date": "2019-07-05"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Cars",
      "title": "Cars",
      "vote_average": 6.7,
      "overview": "El aspirante a campeón de carreras Rayo McQueen está sobre la vía rápida al éxito, la fama y todo lo que él había soñado, hasta que por error toma un desvío inesperado en la polvorienta y solitaria Ruta 66. Su actitud arrogante se desvanece cuando llega a una pequeña comunidad olvidada que le enseña las cosas importantes de la vida que había olvidado.",
      "release_date": "2006-07-06"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Zombieland: Double Tap",
      "title": "Zombieland: Mata y remata",
      "vote_average": 7.5,
      "overview": "En esta secuela y empleando el característico sentido del humor del que hizo gala \"Zombieland\", el grupo de protagonistas tendrá que viajar desde la Casa Blanca hasta el corazón de los Estados Unidos, sobreviviendo a nuevas clases de muertos vivientes que han evolucionado desde lo sucedido hace algunos años, así como a algunos supervivientes humanos rezagados. Pero, por encima de todo, tendrán que tratar de soportar los inconvenientes de convivir entre ellos.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-18"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "The Angry Birds Movie 2",
      "title": "Angry Birds 2: La película",
      "vote_average": 6.5,
      "overview": "Vuelven a la carga Red, el pájaro de color rojo con problemas de mal genio, y sus amigos Chuck, el pájaro amarillo hiperactivo, y Bomb, el pájaro negro muy volátil. En esta segunda parte, los pájaros protagonistas y los intrigantes cerdos de color verde llevarán su conflicto a un nuevo nivel. Y es que, aparecerá una nueva y malvada villana: Zeta, un pájaro que vive en una isla helada. Cuando Zeta lance una bola de hielo sobre la isla en la que se encuentran Red y compañía, nuestros protagonistas tendrán que hacer frente a esta nueva amenaza.",
      "release_date": "2019-08-23"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Toy Story 4",
      "title": "Toy Story 4",
      "vote_average": 7.6,
      "overview": "Woody siempre ha tenido claro cuál es su labor en el mundo y cuál es su prioridad: cuidar a su dueño, ya sea Andy o Bonnie. Sin embargo, Woody descubrirá lo grande que puede ser el mundo para un juguete cuando Forky se convierta en su nuevo compañero de habitación. Los juguetes se embarcarán en una aventura de la que no se olvidarán jamás.",
      "release_date": "2019-06-21"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "El Camino: A Breaking Bad Movie",
      "title": "El Camino: Una película de Breaking Bad",
      "vote_average": 7.1,
      "overview": "Tiempo después de los eventos sucedidos tras el último episodio de la serie \"Breaking Bad\", el fugitivo Jesse Pinkman huye de sus perseguidores, de la ley y de su pasado.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-11"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark",
      "title": "Historias de miedo para contar en la oscuridad",
      "vote_average": 6.3,
      "overview": "Mill Valley, Pennsylvania, noche de Halloween, 1968. Después de gastar una broma a un matón de la escuela, Sarah y sus amigos deciden colarse en una casa supuestamente embrujada que una vez perteneció a la poderosa familia Bellows, desatando fuerzas oscuras que no podrán controlar.",
      "release_date": "2019-08-09"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Aladdin",
      "title": "Aladdín",
      "vote_average": 7.1,
      "overview": "Aladdin es un adorable pero desafortunado ladronzuelo enamorado de la hija del Sultán, la princesa Jasmine. Para intentar conquistarla, acepta el desafío de Jafar, que consiste en entrar a una cueva en mitad del desierto para dar con una lámpara mágica que le concederá todos sus deseos. Allí es donde Aladdín conocerá al Genio, dando inicio a una aventura como nunca antes había imaginado.",
      "release_date": "2019-05-24"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "ワンピーススタンピード",
      "title": "One Piece: Stampede",
      "vote_average": 7.6,
      "overview": "La película tiene lugar durante la Pirates Expo, \"hecha por piratas para piratas\", donde los piratas de todo el mundo, incluidos algunos de sus personajes más infames, se unen a la búsqueda de un gran tesoro para encontrar un tesoro perdido, esta vez el tesoro. Perteneció nada menos que a Gold Roger!",
      "release_date": "2019-11-15"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "It Chapter Two",
      "title": "It Capítulo 2",
      "vote_average": 6.9,
      "overview": "27 años después, los ex-miembros del Club de los Perdedores, que crecieron y se mudaron lejos de Derry, vuelven a unirse tras una devastadora llamada telefónica.",
      "release_date": "2019-09-06"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Rattlesnake",
      "title": "Serpiente de cascabel",
      "vote_average": 5.6,
      "overview": "Una misteriosa desconocida ha salvado a su hija de una mordedura letal de serpiente. Ahora, tiene que devolverle el favor matando a un desconocido.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-25"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Eli",
      "title": "Eli",
      "vote_average": 6,
      "overview": "Eli Miller es un niño que padece una enfermedad autoinmune. Como último recurso, se traslada con sus padres a una mansión libre de gérmenes para recibir tratamiento. Durante su estancia, le atormentan visiones terroríficas que otros consideran alucinaciones. Definitivamente, algo siniestro se esconde entre estas paredes.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-18"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "John Wick",
      "title": "John Wick",
      "vote_average": 7.2,
      "overview": "En Nueva York, John Wick, un asesino a sueldo retirado, vuelve otra vez a la acción para vengarse de los gángsters que le quitaron todo.",
      "release_date": "2014-10-22"
    },
    {
      "original_title": "Gemini Man",
      "title": "Géminis",
      "vote_average": 5.8,
      "overview": "Un asesino a sueldo, demasiado mayor, decide retirarse. Pero esto no le va a resultar tan fácil, pues tendrá que enfrentarse a un clon suyo, mucho más joven.",
      "release_date": "2019-10-11"
    }
  ],
  "total_movies": 20
}
```

```html
const fs = require("fs");
let ListMovie = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/soraw/DigitalHouse/dh-movies/movies.json", 'utf8');
let ListMovieArray = JSON.parse(ListMovie);
var i = 0;
function ayuda() {
    for (i = 0; i < ListMovieArray.total_movies; i++) {
        console.log(ListMovieArray.movies[i].title)

    } 
}
console.log(ayuda())
```

Comment: Can you post the sample of `ListMovieArray`?

Comment: I think this is just the return value of the script. Since there is none, it prints `undefined`.

Comment: @ShivratnaKumar Ready

Comment: @LeonardoCapone Your for loop is working just fine. The last `undefined` that you see is just the return value of `ayuda` function.

Comment: If no return value is specified in function, JavaScript will return undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you see your function is void type function

```
function ayuda() {
    for (i = 0; i < ListMovieArray.total_movies; i++) {
        console.log(ListMovieArray.movies[i].title)

    } 
}
```

which void function return undefined then when you try to console log undefined then it log two undefined

- first undefined is longed by by your function ayuda,
- second undefined is longed by return type of console.log which is
  also void type function so it is undefined

your function call actually looks like

> console.log(undefined)

to fix this you should return some list from fome valid value

> below code is returning array[] of movies title which later can be used by caller

```
function ayuda(ListMovieArray) {
    const titleArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ListMovieArray.total_movies; i++) {
        titleArray.push(ListMovieArray.movies[i].title);
    }
    return titleArray;
}
```

> OR
>
> below cod is longing list item on console and returning true when
>   complete

```
function ayuda(ListMovieArray) {
    for (i = 0; i < ListMovieArray.total_movies; i++) {
        console.log(ListMovieArray.movies[i].title)

    }
return true// or ''; 
}
```

> return type is totally depend you your use case

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify your confusion, here is the updated function:-

```
function ayuda() {
    const titleArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ListMovieArray.total_movies; i++) {
        titleArray.push(ListMovieArray.movies[i].title);
    }
    return titleArray;
}

console.log(ayuda())
```

You will see the result just fine.

Comment: Thanks! 
Where can read about this problem?. I will really appreciate

Comment: @LeonardoCapone You can read it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to not handle any errors. You said you have lot of data, try using promises.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const ayuda = (fileName) => {
  return new Promise((Resolve, Reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if(err) { Reject(err); }
      else {
        Resolve(data.movies.filter(y => y.title))
      }
    })
  })
}
ayuda(PATH_TO_FILE).then(x => console.log(x)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

In last you are getting an error because you are not returning anything in your function.

Basically **console.log()** call your function, once your function called, the execution starts inside the function print the statement inside the for a loop. Once function execution complete it returns undefined and print undefined in outside of your console.

you can do like below:-

```js
const fs = require("fs");
let ListMovie = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/soraw/DigitalHouse/dh-movies/movies.json", 'utf8');
let ListMovieArray = JSON.parse(ListMovie);
var i = 0;
function ayuda() {
    for (i = 0; i < ListMovieArray.total_movies; i++) {
        console.log(ListMovieArray.movies[i].title)

    }
    
    // you can return anythig like 1 or ''
    return 1;
}
console.log(ayuda())

// if you do not want to return anything you can also call the function directly, without using console like this 
ayuda();
```

you can implement this function using es6 also, which is given below:-

```js
const fs = require("fs");
let ListMovie = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/soraw/DigitalHouse/dh-movies/movies.json", 'utf8');
let ListMovieArray = JSON.parse(ListMovie);

const ayuda = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < ListMovieArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(ListMovieArray.movies[i].title);

    }
    return '';
}
console.log(ayuda());
```